# Classcast exception on Scala map operation on List of Strings

Tags: java, scala, classcastexception, typesafe-config

I have a typesafe Config object which contains map datatype. Below is the content of a key in the conf file.

```
test_mapping = {
'15': [8000, 8002],
'5': [500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522],
....
}
```

This is the code I used to read this key from the config.

```
scala> val test = config.getObject("test_mapping").asScala map { case (cat, et) => (cat -> et.unwrapped().asInstanceOf[java.util.ArrayList[String]].asScala.toList) }
test: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map('15' -> List(8001, 8002), '5' -> List(500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522), '8' -> List(800, 801, 802, 803, 804), '2' -> List(200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205...
```

In the above code I understand what I did wrong, conf file contains List of Ints but I used asInstanceOf to cast to List[String] but it works as can be seen above. What I dont understand is why the map function on map values fails with ClassCastException. Please see the code and error below.

```
scala> test.map( { case(c,e) => e.map(identity) } )
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:286)
  at .$anonfun$res105$1(<console>:23)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:237)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.$anonfun$foreach$1(HashMap.scala:149)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:237)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable.foreachEntry$(HashTable.scala:230)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:44)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:149)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:237)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:230)
  at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
  ... 28 elided

scala>
```

Has this got something to do with type erasure on List[_] ? Could someone please explain why the first line which converts to List[String] works but iterating through its elements fails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your guess about erasure is correct.

`List[Integer]` and `List[String]` have the exact same type for the JVM at runtime.
Which means that the cast doesn't actually do anything at runtime. It's a noop.
But when you access individual elements of the list they are accessed as String, since after your cast, the compiler "knows" that this is a `List[String]`.

Now the JVM actually verifies the type and you get `ClassCastException`.
This is not specific to Scala, it works the same in Java (and other typed JVM languages).